# Position datapoint labels in jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm trying to figure out how to change the position of itemLabels in JFreeChart relative to their datapoints (in an XYPlot). I wanna do this because some of my labels end up outside the chart area (and I don't wanna hardcode the chart size, obviously). What's the best way to do this?

I've seen examples using setPositiveItemLabelPosition(), however this method seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the [`ItemLabelPosition`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/ItemLabelPosition.html) using the assorted `set*ItemLabelPosition()` methods specified in the [`XYItemRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYItemRenderer.html) interface.

Comment: I've been using JFreeChart for awhile with no problems...but I can't set an ItemlabelPosition() without a TextAnchor...and my JFreeChart installation doesn't seem to have a TextAnchor class...is there a way to do it without a text anchor, or have I just screwed up my installation?

Comment: [`org.jfree.ui.TextAnchor`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/ui/TextAnchor.html) is part of [`JCommon`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/); it should be in the `JfreeChart` `lib` directory.

Comment: Yep good call - I just had JFreeChart in my Netbeans library and not JCommon.